# Rails Minitest one model validation causes ArgumentError: You need to supply at least one validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, shoulda

In my Rails6 app I've got two model validations which I want to test by Minitest:

```
class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, :status, presence: true
  validates :initial_return do |record, attr, value|
    record.errors.add(attr, 'Add value between -100 and 100') unless value >= -100 && value <= 100
  end
end
```

Minitest:

```
class PortfolioTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    @portfolio = Portfolio.create(name: Faker::Bank.name)
  end

  test 'invalid PortfolioSpotlightFigure, does not fit the range (-100, 100)' do
    @portfolio.initial_return = -101
    assert_not @portfolio.valid?
    @portfolio.initial_return = 101
    assert_not @portfolio.valid?
    @portfolio.initial_return = 50
    assert @portfolio.valid?
  end

  context 'validations' do
    should validate_presence_of(:name)
  end
end
```

Minitest gives the same error for both cases:

> ArgumentError: You need to supply at least one validation

But when I remove validation for `:initial_return` field from `Portfolio` model:

```
  validates :initial_return do |record, attr, value|
    record.errors.add(attr, 'Add value between -100 and 100') unless value >= -100 && value <= 100
```

the test will pass for the `validate_presence_of(:name)` which means that I incorrectly defined that validation. What did I missed?

Comment: why not just do... `validates :initial_return, presence: true, inclusion: -100..100`

Comment: @dbugger the error message is "Initial return is not included in the list" which is not very user friendly. `validate_numericality_of` gives much more useful error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel

```
class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, :status, presence: true
  validates :initial_return,
    numericality: {
      greater_than_or_equal_to: -100,
      less_than_or_equal_to: 100
    }
end
```

And stop carpet bombing your validations in your tests. Test the actual validation and not if the entire object is valid/invalid which leads to false positives and negatives. For example:

```
  test 'invalid PortfolioSpotlightFigure, does not fit the range (-100, 100)' do
    @portfolio.initial_return = -101
    # these will pass even if you comment out the validation on initial_return as 
    # status is nil
    assert_not @portfolio.valid? 
    @portfolio.initial_return = 101
    assert_not @portfolio.valid?
    # Will fail because status is nil
    @portfolio.initial_return = 50
    assert @portfolio.valid?
  end
```

As you can see the test failures will tell you nothing about why the model is valid/invalid.

Instead use one assertion per test and test the actual validation:

```
class PortfolioTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    # you dont need to insert records into the db to test associations
    @portfolio = Portfolio.new
  end

  test 'initial return over 100 is invalid' do
    # arrange
    @portfolio.initial_return = 200
    # act 
    @portfolio.valid?
    # assert
    assert_includes(@portfolio.errors.full_messages, "Initial return must be less than or equal to 100")
  end

  test 'initial return below -100 is invalid' do
    # arrange
    @portfolio.initial_return = -200
    # act 
    @portfolio.valid?
    # assert
    assert_includes(@portfolio.errors.full_messages, "Initial return must be greater than or equal to -100")
  end

  test 'an initial return between -100 and 100 is valid' do
    # arrange
    @portfolio.initial_return = 50
    # act 
    @portfolio.valid?
    # assert
    refute(@portfolio.errors.has_key?(:intial_return))
  end

  # ...
end
```

With shoulda you should be able to use the [`validates_numericality_of` matcher](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/3da09563b10294e987d8cc81c0052a6a249ea380/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validate_numericality_of_matcher.rb):

```
should validate_numericality_of(:initial_return).
            is_greater_than_or_equal_to(-100).
            is_less_than_or_equal_to(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

`@portfolio = Portfolio.create(name: Faker::Bank.name)` in the setup block is expected to already fail.

I don't know if it leads to the actual error but you can't `create` the object when you don't provide the initial `initial_return`. Since it runs against the validation itself.

Because the test case for the numerical range runs you need to make sure that you initial object is valid.
That's why it didn't fail when you removed the `initial_return` validation because the `setup` block was successful without the validation. You were just looking at the wrong end.

So you either use `build` which does not persist the object in the database and does not run the validation initially

```rb
@portfolio = Portfolio.build(name: Faker::Bank.name)
```

or if in case you want to persist the object in the database you have to make sure the setup object is valid

```rb
@portfolio = Portfolio.create(name: Faker::Bank.name, initial_return: 50)
```

Comment: This is a pretty good reason why you shouldn't use `assert @portfolio.valid?` to test validations. It will give a false negative or positive depending on if you have satisfied every other validation in the model.

Comment: Hey totally I'm with you. I just tried to provide a bit of a different approach what the actual issue was and how to solve it. Your answer although perfectly fine provides more of a `do everything different` approach which I'm personally not fond off.

Comment: Yeah sorry if it came off as harsh - you did raise a very good point in that the test setup itself sets it for failure. Sometimes a complete change of course is really the best answer.